# How can I test this function in jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I currently have 0% coverage on branches for this file and I'm not sure how to test this out.

```js
import { RouterState } from '../router';
import { AuthStore } from '../auth';

export const DEFAULT_ROUTE = '/account';
export const HOME_ROUTE = '/';
export const NOT_FOUND_ROUTE = 'not-found';

export const checkForUserSignedIn = () => {
  const authDataStore = new AuthStore();
  if (authDataStore.isAuthenticated) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(new RouterState(HOME_ROUTE));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you'll likely want to provide a "mock implementation" of `AuthStore`.

Mocking is a concept in testing that basically means you "provide an alternate implementation for something", which is used by your application code during the execution of your unit test.

The jest framework provides mocking capabilities - in your case, [module mocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules) is relevant.

I've provided a rough example below to illustrate the concept in the context of your code, and jest. You'll want to provide a mock (or mocks) for `AuthStore`, to be used by your tests to allow you to verify that your application logic ( ie, `checkForUserSignedIn()` ) behaves as expected, under different circumstances ( ie, when `isAuthenticated` is true, false, etc ):

```
import * as User from 'YourUserModule' // ie, where checkForUserSignedIn is defined

// Tell jest you want to mock this module (assuming test located in same path as implementation)
// This module is where AuthStore is defined, which is the particular thing we're interested in mocking
jest.mock('../auth'); 

// Define a mock implementation of '../auth' for use in test
require('../auth')
.mockImplementation(() => {

    // An example of a mocked auth store class. This mocknever returns true for
    // isAuthenticated. We can use this mock to verify the behaviour of the
    // 'reject' code path
    class MockAuthStore {
        get isAuthenticated() {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Return the mock class, to "replace" the existing implementation with this mock when running the test
    return {
        AuthStore : MockAuthStore
    }
})

// Now define your test
it('should reject when user is not authenticated', async () => {

    // An example of how you can verify that checkForUserSignedIn rejects when 
    // new AuthStore().isAuthenticated returns false
    await expect(User.checkForUserSignedIn()).rejects.toBeDefined();
});
```